# Character guessing gaming in C language using 1D array and for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, continue

I intend to skip a particular character using "continue statement" if an iteration("i==[index]"). I want to skip the character at index 5.
Please below is the code. Am a newbie though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char guess[10]="Programmer";
    char choice;
    printf("Welcome to my guessing game\n");
    printf("===============================\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         printf("%c", guess[i]);
          if(i==guess[5])
            continue;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Guess which letter is missing\n");
    scanf(" %c",&choice);

    if(choice==guess[5])
    {
        printf("Excellent! Good point");
    }else
    {
       printf("Ooops! Wrong answer\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char guess[10]="Programmer";` ==> `char guess[]="Programmer";` Just saying. `Programmer` is an *eleven* octet sequence when you include the terminator. I'm not really sure what you think `i==guess[5]` is supposed to be doing. Comparing your enumeration variable `i` against the *content* in `guess[5]` doesn't really sound right, does it? Even if that were addressed, the `continue` seems wrong anyway. You're about to loop anyway, so.. continue to *what* ? I think this needs self-explanation, because that test+continue should be *before* the print.

Comment: You should just say `if (i == 5)` if you want to skip that index. But you need to do it *before* you print.

Comment: @WhozCraig Since he never uses `guess` as a string, the terminator is not needed.

Comment: @WhozCraig in this case it is not a string, but an array of 10 characters. There's no fault there.

Comment: Remove the `continue` which at the end of the code block does nothing. Change to `if(i != 5) printf("%c", guess[i]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree.  Putting a continue in this block doesn't make much sense.  It is so simple the   i != 5 is the best solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane nowhere in my comment did I claim there was a fault. I claimed that initializing an array of 10 from an array of 11 is going miss something (the terminator). That's all, and that can be rectified by letting the compiler do the sizing for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig but you are: *that can be **rectified**.* There is nothing to rectify, as Barmar commented too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix:

Also updated the array size as stated above (It isn't treated as string anywhere, but better safe than sorry).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char guess[12]="Programmer";
    char choice;
    printf("Welcome to my guessing game\n");
    printf("===============================\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if( i != 5 )
        {
            printf("%c", guess[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Guess which letter is missing\n");
    scanf(" %c",&choice);

    if(choice==guess[5])
    {
        printf("Excellent! Good point");
    }else
    {
       printf("Ooops! Wrong answer\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to write continue statement before instruction that you want to skip. Do you want to skip every character which is the same in guess[5] or do you want to skip index 5?

If you to skip all letters which is the same to the letter at index 5:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(guess[i]==guess[5]) continue;
    printf("%c", guess[i]);
}
```

If you want to skip only letter at index 5 try:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(i==5) continue;
    printf("%c", guess[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be comparing with an element of the array, just compare with the index you want to skip.

And you need to put the `continue` before the statements you want to skip. Otherwise the letter has already been printed and continue does nothing useful.

```
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(i==5) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%c", guess[i]);
    }
```